# How can I have a 10cm page footer only on the last page

Tags: reporting-services, reporting-services-2012

I am using reporting services 2012 and want to display a group of elements at the bottom of the last page.

I have tried putting this in the footer and hiding the elements for all but the last page, however this doesn't work very well as there is a large blank space at the bottom of all of the preceding pages.

If there was a way of aligning the elements to the bottom of a page that would work, but I cant see any way of doing that. If there was a way to push the elements to the bottom of the page using a rectangle that has a dynamic height, that would also work, but I also cannot find a way of doing that.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you give more details on "want to display a group of elements". Can you please post a screenshots of your output and RDL. Without looking at your design, I can suggest make your margins as 0 and set  body widths to match page width and height.  Then put a tablix in the end of your body to display it after all the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, page headers and footers must be one constant size in SSRS. That is why you are getting all of that whitespace, and as far as I know, there is no workaround for this.

However, what you can do is page break at the end of your main table / report. Then have another table display the elements you want. Make this second table the height of a full page and put the elements at the bottom. Go into the Tablix Properties and check "Keep together on one page if possible".

If the second table doesn't work, try a subreport.

If you want to have the footer on the same page as the last page of data, this doesn't work. The only way I know of to do that is a major hack: check how many rows come back from the database and calculate how much space they will need to display. Then at the end calculate how big of a rectangle you need to make in between your main table and your second table to push it to the bottom of the page.